# Can we disable few commands at databricks cluster/workspace level?

Tags: shell, apache-spark, databricks, administration

I want to prevent user from executing any harmful commands like dbutils.fs.rm or %sh rm
I can disable shell rm commands. How can I disable dbutils.fs or python/scala specific commands?

Comment: Have you tried anything?Any blocker you are facing?provide those details.

Comment: In databricks we can execute commands in 3 ways: %sh, %scala, %python. So far I can disable rm command in %sh mode. For scala, I found the package which has implementation for rm command. However, I dont have idea about how I can override this function